# Solving $C = C_x x + C_y y + \frac{x B_x + y B_y}{x+y}$ for $x/y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been thinking but I am stumped, and I would love some help.

> How can I rearrange the equation
> $$C = C_x x + C_y y + \frac{x B_x + y B_y}{x+y}$$ to solve for $x/y$? In the solution, $x$ and $y$ should not exist in the RHS if $x/y$ is the LHS.

Some background: $C$, $C_x$, $C_y$, $B_x$, and $B_y$ are all known constants that from some linear models, so the equation here comes from the combination of two linear functions describing a signal by using the weighted average of their concentrations in an aqueous solution.

> Is this possible? If it's not possible, then (1) how can we prove that it's not possible and (2) how could we approximate $x/y$?

Comment: Let $x/y=t$, substitute $x=ty$ in the equation and simplify what you can. If all $y$ cancel out then you got an equation in $t$. Otherwise, it's  not an equation in $t=x/y$ alone.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for suggesting that technique, it worked perfectly! I'm curious to know how you figured it out?

Comment: As a general rule, if you are looking to solve for "something" like $x/y$ it often helps to define an auxiliary variable equal to that something $t=x/y$ and rewrite the equations in terms of the new variable. Back to your question, though, the expression in the latest edit does not match the equation before it, so better doublecheck your calculations or, at least, your notations.

Comment: 2 points. Please post you answer in the answer area and mark it as an answer. Second, where did the $C_x x$ and $C_y y$ go after the substitution?

Comment: @NoChance I'd done something weird. I fixed my mistake, but now I'm just seeing that there are still several $y$ terms left. I'm left with $C(t+1)-b_x t + b_y = C_x yt(t+1)+C_y y(t+1)$. This doesn't seem to be able to be solved for $t$ while getting rid of $y$.

Comment: @dxiv I found the problem! But I'm still stumped.

Comment: I am not sure you can get rid of $x$ and/or $y$ from R.H.S entirely.

Comment: @hn6 That means you *can't* solve it for $x/y$. Most such equations can't be solved for $x/y$. Your equation is of the form $f(x,y)=0$ which usually defines a curve in the $x-y$ plane. For the points on that curve $x/y$ will not be constant, unless the curve happens to be a straight line through the origin, so you can't solve it for $x/y$. As about the question you added at the end "*how could we approximate $x/y$*" that can't be answered in any meaningful way unless you provide a lot more details on what the ranges of the parameters and the range of the approximation are supposed to be.

Comment: @dxiv That makes sense. $[C, x, y]\in (1.5,\infty)$  As for the coefficients: $C_x$ and $C_y$ are nearly but not quite equal, and $b_x$ is awfully close to $b_y$. $C_x$ and $C_y$ are approximately 0.5. $b_x$ and $b_y$ are about 1.5.

Comment: How could I prove that there is a continuum of values of $x/y$ that satisfy the equation?

Comment: @hn6 You wrote the equation in $t,y$ earlier. For each $t \ne - \frac{C_y}{C_x}$ you can solve it for $y = \frac{(C-B_x)t + C - b_y}{(C_x t + C_y)(t+1)}$.